# Qt5 for Android: incompatible ABI

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I recently installed Qt5 and works like a charm for API 17 and armeabi-v7a.
But I added second AVD with other parameters (of course, I installed packages in AVD settings). Now, I can't compile first project and new project for API10. When check any toolchain (armeabi or armeabi-v7a), window for choose AVD says that I don't have compatible AVD (in message displays that AVD supports `default/armeabi` or  `default/armeabi-v7a`).
Anyone know how I can repair this? I think that problem is with "`default/`"...

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I'm seeing exactly the same symptoms with QtCreator 3.0.2 and Qt 5.2.1 on Linux x86_64.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There seems to be another workaround for this problem:

In QtCreator -> Projects -> BuildEnvironment add the variable

> ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH=default/armeabi-v7a

Then the AVDs are shown as compatible.

Comment: This is actually the best answer

Comment: This solution worked for me,but after a while I discovered that it broke my compilation, I couldn't deploy any app on AVD. Please read : http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-2/#comment-3496

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that this is indeed a changed behaviour in the latest version of the Android SDK, where it lists AVDs with prefixed tag information. So instead of `armeabi-v7a` it's returning `default/armeabi-v7a`, resulting in QtCreator complaining that the ABI is not supported.

Here is the QtCreator bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11658

You can either wait for a new QtCreator to be released after the patch goes in (it's being reviewed at the moment), or you can try to downgrade your Android SDK Tools from version 22.6 to something that reports only `ABI: armeabi-v7a` instead of `Tag/ABI: default/armeabi-v7a` when you execute `android list avd`

Comment: Thanks, It confirmed my assumptions

Answer (score 3):

Spent some time figuring out how to downgrade from Android SDK Tools 22.6. Here's how to downgrade:

1. Download [Android SDK Tools 22.3](http://ady.my/viewer/tool.html)
2. Rename tools-folder to tools-22.6 under SDK (eg. ~/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools)
3. Extract the downloaded tools to above path