# Qt android- incompatible abi error

Tags: android, qt

I'm trying to build Qt(5.7) for android on windows platform.
I'm getting this error on running the application.
In compile output this is displayed-
Error while building/deploying project analogclock (kit: Android for ANDROID TARGET_ARCH=armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.1)) When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

I tried this solution-
https://forum.qt.io/topic/39691/android-deployment-error-abi-is-incompatible/2 and these too [Qt5 for Android: incompatible ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238649/qt5-for-android-incompatible-abi)
but still this error flags.

Any help would be appreciated. :)